# Invalid expression of term else

Tags: c#, command-line, console, console-application

I am creating a  tic tac toe game and for the play again section i am getting an invaild expression of term else, Can anyone help? it worked before i added the introduction procedure 
Thanks in advance

```
static void playAgainMsg(String message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message + "Do you want to play again? Y/N"); // Displaying the resukt of the game and asking the user if they would like to play again and tells them to input Y or N
        if 
        {
            (Console.ReadLine().Equals("Y")) // This reads the line to check the user input
            strPlaysAgain.Equals("Y");
            introduction(); <---- worked before this was added...
        }   
        else
        {
            strPlaysAgain.Equals("N"); // This Changes the value from the default value of Y to N so that it exits the While loop for PlaysAgain.
            Console.Clear(); //Clears the console so that the game board is removed.
            MainMenu();  // returns the user back to the introduction -  edit to be main menu with an exit feature, highscores
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't test anything with the `if`. Plus, `str1.Equals(str2)` is a test. You have to use `=` to assign a value.

```
static void playAgainMsg(String message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message + "Do you want to play again? Y/N"); 
            if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("Y"))
            {
                strPlaysAgain = "Y";
                introduction();
            }   
            else
            {
                strPlaysAgain = "N"; 
                Console.Clear(); removed.
                MainMenu();  
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you misaligned the condition

```
        if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("Y")) //<------------
        {
             // This reads the line to check the user input
            strPlaysAgain.Equals("Y");
            introduction();
        }   
        else
        {
            strPlaysAgain.Equals("N"); // This Changes the value from the default value of Y to N so that it exits the While loop for PlaysAgain.
            Console.Clear(); //Clears the console so that the game board is removed.
            MainMenu();  // returns the user back to the introduction -  edit to be main menu with an exit feature, highscores
        }
```